# refs in React to emulate static variables

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

From the [Hooks FAQ](https://legacy.reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#is-there-something-like-instance-variables) in the old (and no longer updated) React documentation:

> **Is there something like instance variables?**
>
> Yes! The useRef() Hook isn’t just for DOM refs. The “ref” object is a generic container whose current property is mutable and can hold any value, similar to an instance property on a class.
>
> You can write to it from inside useEffect:
>
> ```
> function Timer() {
>   const intervalRef = useRef();
>   useEffect(() => {
>    const id = setInterval(() => {
>      // ...
>    });
>    intervalRef.current = id;    return () => {
>      clearInterval(intervalRef.current);
>    };
>  });
>
>  // ...
> }
> ```

In the new documentation a [similar example](https://react.dev/learn/referencing-values-with-refs) is given.

Are there any alternatives?

Can't you just define a variable outside of the component, which is accessible in this scope? What are the downsides of the latter approach, aside from obviously introducing a file-scoped global variable?

I didn't explicitly mention it, but the fundamental difference to `useState` is that that triggers a re-render. So no, `useState` isn't an alternative.

Comment: > Are there any alternatives? <

useState, notably.

Comment: "Can't you just define a variable outside of the component" of course "What are the downsides" since you want *static*, no downsides.

Comment: Well variables in modules are kind of private or if you export them like readonly. If you want them to be not only readable but writable from other modules I'd use a property on the exported component itself

Answer (score 1):

In your case, you don't need to use an external variable, or a ref. `useEffect` is a closure, and unless the dependencies of `useEffect` change, the closure will maintain the variable values:

```
function Timer() {
  useEffect(() => {
    const id = setInterval(() => {
      // ...
    });

    return () => {
      clearInterval(id);
    };
  }, []); // use an empty dependencies array

  // ...
}
```